# Does OpenGeo Suite no longer exist? What is a good alternative?

Tags: boundless-suite

I've been trying to get a copy of open geo suite to work through some tutorials and create a few things. From what I can tell, the most recent version is 4.8. Theres plenty of documentation out there related to the suite and to the tutorials. However, when I try to go to any of boundlesses sites related to this, it seems like they have changed their format entirely and no longer offer any support of this (even previous versions). Anyone have a suggestion for where I can get it now?

"Impossible. Perhaps the archives are incomplete."

"If an item does not appear in our records, it does not exist."

EDIT: I'd also like to add that I personally find it a bit irritating that a company that frames itself as open-source friendly would eliminate such a tool.

Comment: As has been pointed out in some of the answers, OpenGeo Suite is no longer maintained, and has been replaced by Boundless Server. In my answer I pointed to a blog post that describes how to glue most of the pieces together yourself. But you might also want to take a look at GeoNode - http://geonode.org/. GenoNode is actually much closer to what Boundless Server is than the (now very old) OpenGeo Suite.

Answer (score 9):

Boundless were bought out by or merged with Planet a couple of months ago - they are now Planet Federal. The Boundless open source stack is no longer being maintained, unfortunately.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Geoserver Explorer gone with it.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this  problem a year ago, and wrote a blog post about my work-around.

The OpenGeo Suite (or more recently, Boundless Suite) is made up entirely of other open source projects. As Daniel points out, the Boundless Suite is available on GitHub. But it requires building from a cloned version of the repository. I found it much easier to just make my own version of the OpenGeo/Bouindless Suite. The basic steps are:

1. Set up a GeoServer instance on an Ubuntu Server (home server, AWS,
   GPC, what ever you have)
2. Add a Postgresql/PostGIS database to the server
3. Install QGIS as a desktop client
4. Optionally, Add the GeoServer Explorer plugin to QGIS (At the time
   this was hosted by Boundless. I do not know the current state of
   this plugin)

Essentially, I glued all the pieces of the OpenGeo Suite together myself. The post is here:
[Open Source Spatial Data Processing Suite](http://www.donmeltz.com/open-source-spatial-data-processing-suite/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a docker container for the suite that was built two years ago:
https://hub.docker.com/r/devdattat/docker-opengeosuite/

If you were following the tutorial from PostGis/documentation it looks as though this may be the updated version:
https://learning-center.boundlessgeo.com/suite/workshop/tutorial-postgis-intro/

Boundless Desktop may be the new version of the suite, I'm not certain as didn't use the previous versions but hope this helps someone as I've been chasing my tail with this!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this discussion looking about OpenGeo-Suite status (2019),
and I also found this:

> OpenGeoSuite is not being updated/published anymore, and the newer versions (Boundless Server) are only being made available customers. For a long time Boundless made previous versions available publicly, but this was stopped due to security concerns.
>   ...

from: [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/8rakea/opengeo_suite_still_relevant/)

Personally I'm more and more orietated on single Open-source components (Mapserver + postgress + postgis + web-gis clients) instead of great and optimistic packages that seems always to be pre-commercial relaises. It's harder to learn but you can go on, year by year, without too many surprises or being compelled to restart from zero, when you realized they dismiss open-source resources.

Answer (score 0):

Found this Github repo

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite

Title says: Boundless Suite (formerly OpenGeo Suite).
Not sure it's what you are looking for, but the title is promissing